# Recursively Find A Path

Tags: recursion, path, theory, radix

I have a series of numbers ranging from 0-9. Each number represents a position with an x and y co-ordinate. So, position 0 could represent (5, 5) or something similar, always (x, y). Now what I need to do is recursively bash each possible route using 5 positions to get the position given by a user. So for example:

```
Input = (1, 2) //This is the co-ordinate the user gives.
```

Now given this input it should take every possible path and find the shortest one. Some paths could be:

```
start 0 1 2 3 4 input
start 0 1 2 3 5 input
start 0 1 2 3 6 input
start 0 1 2 3 7 input
start 0 1 2 4 3 input
start 1 0 2 3 5 input
and so on....
```

It could be any combination of 5 numbers from the 0-9. It must end at the input destination and begin at start destination. Numbers cannot be reused. So I need to recursively add all the distances for a given course (ex. start 0 1 2 3 4 input) and find the shortest possible course while going through those 5 points.

Question: What would the base and recursive case be?

Comment: Take a look at Dijkstra's_algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to do is generate all combinations of size k (the length of the path) from the set {1,..,n}, and then calculate the value of the path for it.

Here's a C# code sample:

```
void OPTPathForKSteps(List<int> currentPath, List<int> remainingPositions, int remainingSteps)
    {
        if (remainingSteps == 0)
        {
             // currentPath now contains a combination of k positions
             // do something with currentPath...
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < remainingPositions.Count; i++)
            {
                int TempPositionIndex = remainingPositions[i];
                currentPath.Add(TempPositionIndex);
                remainingPositions.RemoveAt(i);

                OPTPathForKSteps(currentPath, remainingPositions, remainingSteps - 1);

                remainingPositions.Insert(i, TempPositionIndex);
                currentPath.RemoveAt(currentPath.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the initial call for the function (assume Positions is an integer list of 0...n positions, and k is the length of the path):

```
OPTPathForKSteps(new List<int>(), Positions, K);
```

You can change the function and add arguments so it will return the optimal path and minimal value.
There are other (maybe shorter) ways to create these combinations, the good thing about my implementation is that it is light on the memory, and doesn't require storing all the possible combinations.